# UIScrollView does not scroll as wanted at the bottom

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

The following image explains pretty much the issue I am having:

[image: UIScrollView not scrolling at the bottom]

I have these obligated lines of code:

```
(linesScrollView, and its content view: called contentScrollable)

self.linesScrollView.delegate = self;
    [self.linesScrollView setContentSize:self.contentScrollable.frame.size];
```

And the scroll view does not scroll completely at the bottom of the screen, but it scrolls well at the top of the screen.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please add, via NSLog output, the frames of linesScrollView and especially contentScrollable.  Isn't quite clear that the latter is not what you expect?

Comment: Check the size of the scroll view's frame

Answer (score 0):

Try to  uncheck the Adjust Scroll View Inset. Property of VIEWCONTROLLER

http://screencast.com/t/h7g9toqM2ENn